# Displaying a shadow on views that will resize

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadows

I want my views to have shadows. When I first added shadows to all my views I quickly encountered a problem, the UI was very laggy. I then realised that I should instead use `UIBezierPath` and set `shouldRasterize` to `true` when drawing shadows.
Everything became silky smooth again but with one problem, these shadows are static. They won't resize with the views. 
These views are each in their own `UITableViewCell` and these cell's heights are dynamically adjusted to fit the content in the views. But when a certain cell resizes (with an animation) I would like the views and their shadows to resize as well but they won't because they are rasterized.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Will it be appropriate to make this shadow stretchable?
If so, you can try drawing your shadow once to a shared UIImage (and cache it)
[UIBezierPath to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974036/uibezierpath-to-uiimage)

And then set background UIImageViews with resizeable UIImage to your views with the help of UIImage's method

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:
```

You will have one image for all shadows that will be added as background UIImageView to your views.

Comment: As a simpler solution, you can try to call setNeedsDisplay to your background view after view resizes (this causes your view and view hierarchy to be re-rendered).